# Update git branch with master without merge

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am the sole developer working on a fairly big project. I made several important changes in `master` and I'm about to resume working on a `feature` branch that has fallen behind a good deal. The `feature` branch really does need the changes from `master` but I do not want to merge the changes into `master` until the work on `feature` is ready for release. I think this is a pretty straight forward case for rebasing, but I am not sure. Below is a very boiled down version of my situation (the actual history is much longer).

```
* 0e109d5 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) latest commit
* 9188511 - major schema change
| * d3472a5 - (origin/feature, feature) feature branch commit
| * 6c36837 - Start of feature branch
|/  
*   80d93a8 - Base commit
```

1. I did push `feature` to the remote for safe-keeping, which is normally a bad thing for rebasing. But since it hasn't been shared with anyone else, can I simply delete the remote branch and continue like it never existed? My `remote` is there simply for offline storage and security (it is a plain git server, not github).
2. Assuming the remote branch is no longer an issue, can I just rebase `master` onto `feature` and just continue working on `feature` without also fast-forwarding `master` to the last feature branch commit?
3. I don't think I need to cherry pick because `feature` pretty much needs all the changes in `master`.
4. I think I can also just make a patch file (from the base commit to `HEAD` and try applying it to `feature`.

Any advice is appreciated. I love git, but I have no experience rebasing yet.

Comment: 1. You can merge master to feature locally. 2. If you want to save your feature to remote server, then you can create a new branch on the  remote, and save you local feature to it, and don't effect the master. 3. check this for advise: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since your remote `feature` branch exists simply for safe-keeping purpose and has not been shared with anyone else, it is certainly safe to delete the branch or force-push to it. You can rebase your current work at branch `feature` on `master`, and continue working on it:

```
# while staying at feature branch
git rebase master
```

Depending on the changes in master, you may have to resolve some conflicts during the rebase.

To update the remote safe-keeping branch (which no one else has seen other than yourself):

```
git push -f origin feature
```

The history will then look like:

```
* newsha1 - (feature, origin/feature) feature branch commit
* newsha2 - Start of feature branch
* 0e109d5 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) latest commit
* 9188511 - major schema change
* 80d93a8 - Base commit
```

In essence, the commit history grows linearly, as if you only started the work on `feature` after you have introduced the changes in `master`.

Comment: I've just tried this out and it gives me exactly what I wanted. `feature` has all of the changes in `master` and `master` is still clean. Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the help
Quick tip for beginners:
make sure to  `git rebase origin/main`
to rebase on the up-to-date remote main branch

Answer (score 11):

I think what you want here is to `rebase` `feature` onto `master`. Just do:

```
git rebase master feature
```

If you are currently on `feature` branch, just:

```
git rebase master
```

For your questions:

1. It deosn't matter since you are the sole developer. After the `rebase`, just push to your remote branch with `-f` or `--force-with-lease`. The latter one is more safe, but no difference here for sole developer.

   ```
   git push --force-with-lease origin feature
   ```
2. Yes, you don't need to fast-forwarding master at the moment. You can do it after you finish work on `feature`. You can use `--ff-only` to allow only fast-forward merge to keep your history linear.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge --ff-only feature
   ```
3. Yes, no `cherry pick` is needed here.
4. No need to use patch. `Patch` is used to distribute your changes to others.

   PS. `git` is really friendly with `patch`. You can do it either way as follows.

   ```
   git diff > some.patch
   git apply some.patch
   ```

   Or

   ```
   git diff > some.patch
   patch -p1 < some.patch
   ```

   Or

   ```
   git diff --no-prefix > some.patch
   patch -p0 < some.patch
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me as though you simply want to merge master into your feature branch?

`git checkout feature-branch
git merge master`

will attempt to move all of the commits in master into your feature branch, so that you can deal with conflicts / merge issues there, without touching the current state of `master`.

Comment: But won't that also fast-forward `master` to the last commit of `feature`? I really want to keep `master` as clean as possible.